# How to avoid exception from hresult 0x800a03ec while adding the excel file in C# program

Tags: c#

I am trying to add existing excel file into workbook in C#, I am getting the exception from hresult 0x800a03ec. My code is like

Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets.Add("C:\Users\..\Sheet11");

How can I avoid the error and add existing excel sheet? Pleasehelp. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please add exception message and detail and more code (the method that throw exception).

Comment: COM exceptions are difficult to decipher,you will have to post your code

Answer (score 0):

If your code is `.Add("C:\Users\..\Sheet11");` than you have issues with incorrectly escaped string. 
Your file name should be

- either `@"C:\Users\My\Sheet11.xls"` (notice `@` at the beginning that meas use varbatim string)
- or `"C:\\Users\\My\Sheet11.xls"` (notice `\\` - escape for "\" symbol).

Comment: may be typing mistake here, but in the code I am using "C:\\Users\\my\\Sheet11"

Comment: Can anybody help me how to add existing excel sheet from desktop to workbook of C# project